# cannot open links sent in sms text messages

Tags: android, iphone, sms

im sending links via sms

like so:

hello, please click on http://example.com/Axcsy

some of the users call back with a problem that they cannot connect,
after inspected i realized that the link has been cut after they pressed on it.
so when they press it they get to http://example.com,
when they copy paste the entire link it works ofc...

is this a known issue or some setting that they changed?

I don't know of any issue that can cause this. 
All i can think of is that they didnt click on it and just copy pasted it.

Note: it happened with only a few users (maybe 5 out of thousands), it has nothing to do with model type or android/IOS version (as far as i know, i checked with users that have the same model...)

if anyone has any clue why this is happening please answer,

thanks to anyone who replys

Answer (score 0):

The users are probably using a text messaging app that causes this problem. Many users do not realize that Android can have different text messaging apps - and therefore don't realize they can change them.

Some of your users may have deliberately changed it and can tell you what app they are using, and they could then tell you so you can contact the developer. Even a provider's default app may have been created wrong or has a bug.